# Python 3.2 crashing when I try to save file

Tags: python, macos, python-idle, activetcl

Running Mac OSX 10.6.6.

I installed python 3.2 last night on my computer. I played with some code in IDLE, but never ended up saving any of my work.

This morning, I tried to  set up my Interactive Start Up File, as recommended [here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing), but when I save the file as startup.py (or anything really) the entire application crashes. In other words, IDLE quits unexpectedly and this message comes on my screen.

```
Process:         Python [3237]
Path:            /Applications/Python 3.2/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.IDLE
Version:         3.2.0 (3.2.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [90]

Date/Time:       2011-05-02 10:57:43.996 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          2189426 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           5
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  5403 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5
Anonymous UUID:                      XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000012
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Please note, I have blocked out the Anonymous UUID above because I'm not sure if this is sensitive information. Also, this message is not being generated by python, but my OS.

Please help.

Comment: Please post to http://bugs.python.org/. Here is not a Python bug tracker.

Comment: Clearly he didn't think this is a bug, why voting him down?

Comment: A core dump, submitted in a bug tracker, would be useful.

Comment: In the meantime, you might want to write your Python script in a more capable editor (say, vim, emacs, even notepad++, ...).

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed the problem by installing Active State.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to install [ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.5](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) as [explained in detail here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).  As described, there are serious known problems with the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 in Mac OS 10.6.  In fact, you should have seen a warning in the IDLE shell about not using the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk and you should have seen a warning when installing Python 3.2.

If you *have* already installed ActiveState `Tcl/Tk` 8.5 and are seeing crashes, then please open an issue at http://bugs.python.org.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Much better advice than the "Here is not a Python bug tracker" comment by the other user.

Comment: Good.  I'm sorry, though, that you didn't see or respond to the warnings when installing and when running.  I tried to make them obvious.

Comment: My way of installing things is to just click until it's finished. That's why I missed the warnings. Of course, I don't think it's the best way of doing things, but then again, that's probably why I'm a noob.